# Convert a pandas column of int to timestamp datatype when column name is not known

Tags: python, pandas

Hi my use case is I have dynamic names of datetime field and date will be some thing like unix timestamp . so every time there could be different column name and there can be multiple date filed . so how I can do this ? for now if I do hardcode for column name this works for me

```
df['date'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['date'], unit='s')
```

but not sure how I can make this for dynamic names and multiple fields with pandas

Comment: Hi, can you use the column index, something like `df.iloc[:, indx]` ?

Comment: Do the column names have a pattern?

Comment: @Corralien No always random and unknown

Comment: @MohamedAliJAMAOUI didn't get can you please give example ?

Comment: but values are always numbers like `1673458455`?

Comment: @Corralien yes values resulting this way for date field

Comment: So you can try to convert all columns as `DatetimeIndex` then just keep ones where conversion succeeded (above 90% for example)? Please provide a sample of one of your dataframes.

Comment: @Corralien  you can check this example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-pandas-to_datetime-with-timestamps/   . for example my column name is timestamps

Answer (score 0):

As suggested on my comment, you can try to convert all columns as DatetimeIndex then just keep one where conversion succeeded?

```
# Inspired from @mozway, https://stackoverflow.com/a/75106101/15239951
def find_datetime_col(df):
    mask = df.astype(str).apply(pd.to_datetime, errors='coerce').notna()
    return mask.mean().idxmax()

col = find_datetime_col(df)
print(col)

# Output
Heading 1
```

Input dataframe:

```
>>> df
   Heading 1  Heading 2  Heading 3  Heading 4
0 2023-01-01         34         12         34
1 2023-01-02         42         99         42
2 2023-01-03         42         99         42
3 2023-01-04         42         99         42
```